# docker-machine: Can't access container's web server from host

Tags: docker

I just installed Docker with Docker-Toolbox on my Mac using homebrew: [install docker with homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32744780/install-docker-toolbox-on-a-mac-via-command-line)

After creating and configuring a Container with Rails, Postgres and starting docker-compose up everything looks fine but i can't access the webserver from host.

The output of

```
$ docker-compose up

dummy_1    | I, [2016-03-30T14:55:53.130639 #6]  INFO -- : listening on addr=0.0.0.0:8000 fd=10
```

When i type in Google Chrome the url http://0.0.0.0:8000/ i get

```
This site can’t be reached

0.0.0.0 refused to connect.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

So i tried

```
$ docker-machine env dummy
```

with the following output:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/choi/.docker/machine/machines/dummy"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="dummy"
```

When i try in Chrome `http://192.168.99.100:2376` i get a blank file downloaded. Why is it so? I expect the default greeting page of my Rails App.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 isn't the IP address of your container - "listening on 0.0.0.0" means the server will accept connections on any network interface. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`192.168.99.100` is the IP of your Docker host, in this instance. You need to expose the port of your container and then you will be able to connect to it from the outside world.

I'm not familiar with Docker Compose, but the log you have posted *suggests* port 8000 is exposed. Try, therefore, `http://192.168.99.100:8000`.

(The reason `http://192.168.99.100:2376` doesn't work is because that's the address and port of the Docker daemon itself, which isn't HTTP-based. As for `0.0.0.0`: This is the address which your web server is listening on *inside* the container and equates to all external connections therein. However, without any ports exposed, there's no way in!)

Comment: Special thanks for pointing out that container needs to be accessed via machine's IP. I thought it should be `localhost`, but it seems in context of machine everything goes through it...

Comment: I'm running into a problem on Win10 Home where <docker-machine ip>:<exposed port> does not let me hit my app server which is listening on localhost:8080 inside the container, where 8080 in the container is mapped to 3000 <exposed port> on my host.  (0.0.0.0:8080->3000/tcp)

Still searching for root cause.

Comment: Took me sometime but found this answer FINALLYYY! Thanks

Comment: I did this but still can't access it from the browser. It does return correctly via curl. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 21):

For those who tried `localhost:4000` as [the tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#pull-and-run-the-image-from-the-remote-repository) said but failed:

Input this:

```
$ docker-machine env
```

and you will see something like:

```
export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://192.168.99.100:2376"
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/choi/.docker/machine/machines/dummy"
export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="dummy"
```

So you get the IP: `192.168.99.100`. Then just visit `192.168.99.100:4000`, as `ip:your_port`.

Comment: I just get Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists

Comment: @Geordie You need to install docker toolbox for that to work

Answer (score 18):

You can find a right address to call your page this way
First, find the CONTAINER ID by:

```
$ docker ps
```

You will get the information like this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
56dd4d582b08        abc01               "python app.py"     10 minutes ago      Up 11 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:80->4000/tcp   flamboyant_bell
```

Now you know the port: 4000 (scroll right this row). So that the address should be like this:

```
http://192.168.99.100:4000/
```

However, you can double check:

```
$ docker port 56dd4d582b08
```

You will get in this case the following info:

```
4000/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80
```

Now you can try to look you project at

```
http://192.168.99.100:4000/
```

Comment: where did you get that ip address from?

Comment: same question as @surfer190

Comment: Hi @mirana, if you scroll to the right the row beginning from  "CONTAINER ID", you will see. Please, notify, if it solves you question

Comment: The IP address is the LAN IP address of the host machine running Docker - it was provided in the question. The output of docker ps only provides 0.0.0.0

Comment: @Mattygabe what if no IP shows up and you only see the port?

Comment: I followed your steps and got the same output but I cannot access my server. I think I have to expose a port. At least I am on the right track

Comment: OP got the IP using `docker-machine`

Answer (score 11):

After exposed the port, you can access the web app by the internal IP address created by docker. You can get the IP address using the container's name running the command:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' 'container name here'
```

Let's say that you got the IP `172.17.0.2`. You can run `open http://172.17.0.2:8000`

Comment: This wont work because he is running docker using docker machine. The containers you create in docker machine are accessible via the host's address and not directly.

Comment: You are right, @willa. But in the older versions it was possible to access the container's private IP after adding an route as `sudo route -n add 172.17.0.0/16 $(docker-machine ip dev)`.

Comment: @GustavoHenrique I'm using Docker Desktop for windows and I want to run httpd image but can't via the browser ! the ip address is `172.17.0.2:<port>` still can't access it !

Comment: What if an output of your command is empty?

Comment: This is a surprisingly helpful answer - it helped me realized I had passed the two ports to `docker run -p` backward. Thank you.