# docker-machine - unable to connect to rest url

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am running an application in docker setup locally [Installed docker using homebrew in Mac].

I get `Could not get any response` from postman or `Empty reply from server` in curl calls.

I tried all the solutions mentioned in [docker-machine: Can't access container's web server from host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36312750/docker-machine-cant-access-containers-web-server-from-host), but none worked for me. I am not sure why I am not able to access the URL.

I am attaching the docker ps and docker-machine env output.

[image]

I am also attaching my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.2'
services:
  details:
    image:  localhost:5000/my-details-1
    container_name: details
    #build: ./details
    expose:
      - 9080
  ratings:
    image: localhost:5000/my-ratings-1
    container_name: ratings
    #build: ./ratings
    expose:
      - 9080
  reviews:
    image: localhost:5000/my-reviews-1
    container_name: reviews
    #build: ./reviews/reviews-wlpcfg
    expose:
      - 9080
  restwrapjdbc:
    image: localhost:5000/my-restwrapjdbc
    container_name: restwrapjdbc
    #build: ./RestWrapJDBC
    expose:
      - 8085
  mirest:
    image: localhost:5000/my-mirest
    container_name: mirest
    #build: ./MIRest
    #network_mode: "host"
    expose:
      - 8085
    ports:
      - target: 8085
        published: 8085
        protocol: tcp
        mode: hosts
```

### EDITED:

I forgot to include the `url-pattern` from `web.xml`. Including that string to the url worked.

Comment: I can't run that `docker-compose.yml` file; it looks like you attached an image instead of the actual contents of the file.  Can you delete these two screen shots and replace them?

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong port maping. Seems like your image exposes port 8080. But you map 8085 to 8085.

Instead:

```
expose:
      - 8085
ports:
      - target: 8085
        published: 8085
        protocol: tcp
        mode: hosts
```

write

```
ports:
      - 8085:8080
```

Comment: I get the following errors after your suggested changes when I run 
`curl http://localhost:8085/ -> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found`
`curl http://192.168.99.101:8085/ -> connection refused.`

Comment: ```curl http://localhost:8085/ HTTP Status 404``` So that means your docker responds now! You have to add correct path.

Comment: Also you can check how your app responds inside container. Just execute:
```docker exec -it mirest /bin/bash```
And now you can check curl to localhost inside container.

Comment: Still status 404-Not found.

Comment: Did you update your path? How your REST api responds within development environment?

Comment: Also make sure you specify your application does not check request type to be JSON.

Comment: I figured that the `web.xml` had the `url-pattern` included. Post including, it worked. Thanks for your help!